# How can change tabspecification text into another tab activity?

Tags: android

I am working in android. I have used tab host and tab widget. I have 4 activity to add as view.

this is my program:

```
public class TabDemo extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost=getTabHost();
        // no need to call TabHost.Setup()        

        //First Tab
        TabSpec spec1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 1");
        spec1.setIndicator("Tab 1",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sun));
        Intent in1=new Intent(this, Act1.class);
        spec1.setContent(in1);

        TabSpec spec2=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 2");
        spec2.setIndicator("Tab 2",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chart));
        Intent in2=new Intent(this,Act2.class);
        spec2.setContent(in2);

        tabHost.addTab(spec2);
        tabHost.addTab(spec3);
    }
}
```

Now in second Activity I want to change this text "Check-In" on a button click.

```
spec2.setIndicator("Check-In",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chart));
```

How can I change setIndicator text of super class in its child class?

If you have any other query related to my question please feel ask.

Comment: put that "checkin" in global variable and update that global variable on a particular event that you want

Comment: Yes sir i done that but this is not working till this checkin activity is not loaded again. please suggest me what should i do..?

Comment: you can implement onTabChangedListenr in your activity and work for that

Answer (score 0):

You can send broadcast intent on button click and listen for this intent in activity with tabhost.

Comment: To send broadcast:
`sendBroadcast(new Intent("change_caption_please"));`
And broadcast receiver:
`BroadcastReceiver receiver = () {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if ("change_caption_please".equals(intent.getAction()) ...
    }
};
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("change_caption_please");`

Comment: You even can store tab caption in shared preferences, so it be persistent between program launches. There are many ways to go :-)